# Query in callback column

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-3, grocery-crud

I want to know how and where to write sql querys in order to show items by id and avoid to list all of them. As you can see, i have implemented a callback column, but it list all and not the elements by id.

**Controller (callback column)**

```
$crud->set_table('intervaloshorarios');

        //$crud->columns('intervaloHorario', 'numeroVehiculos');

        $crud->display_as('idCarga', 'Nº Entrega');
        $crud->set_subject('Intervalos');
        $crud->set_relation('idIntervaloHorario', 'entregas', 'numeroEntrega');
        //Para cambiar los nombres de las columnas usar el display_as
        //http://www.grocerycrud.com/documentation/options_functions/display_as
        $crud->display_as('intervaloHorario', 'Intervalos Horarios')->display_as('numeroVehiculos', 'Plazas Disponibles');
        $crud->callback_column('intervaloHorario', array($this, '_callback_intervalo_horario'));
```

**Callback function**

```
public function _callback_intervalo_horario($intervaloHorario, $row) {

        return "<a href='" . base_url('index.php/Entregas_Controller/entregas_lista/' . $row->idIntervaloHorario) . "'>$intervaloHorario</a>";
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The callback calls to the same webpage ?

Try with this:

```
if ( $this->uri->segment(3) != '' ) {
    $crud->where('idIntervaloHorario', $this->uri->segment(3));
}
```